# Setting the control's parent in form designer

Tags: c#

This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446542.aspx) offers some good advice about manually customising the form designer to improve performance:

- Reduce the number of method and property calls on controls during startup. For example, Controls.Bounds is a better option than calls to Control.Location and Control.Size.
- Create the form from the top down. In nested control hierarchies, set the parent property of containers (using the above rule) before adding controls to the container. As in the BigForm application, the panels had their parent property set to the form before the 40 controls were connected to the panel. If further containers exist lower in the hierarchy, the same changes should be applied.

I have followed the 1st bit of advice, replacing:

```
this.MyControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
this.MyControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(630, 90);
```

with:

```
this.MyControl.Bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(5, 5, 630, 90);
```

This resulted in a super 20% (about 200ms) speed-up on one form. I'm trying to follow the 2nd bit of advice and not quite sure how to proceed. The `Designer.cs` file contains code like this:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.pnlHeader);
```

but not the code I was expecting (according to the example):

```
this.pnHeader.Parent = this;    // Not in the Designer
```

The code `this.Controls.Add(this.pnlHeader);` appears at the bottom of `InitializeComponent`. Is the advice suggesting moving the code to the top or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

i found [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446535.aspx#netcfimproveformloadperf_topic4) which explain the issue as following:

> Another method for improving performance is to initialize the controls
>   in the control tree top-down. For example, if you have a panel control
>   with many controls in it, create the panel first, and then add the
>   controls to the panel. Also, setting the parent property of the
>   control instead of adding to the Controls collection can improve
>   performance.

For example, consider adding a textbox to a panel's control collection:

**Before optimization:**

```
// Create a new panel and textbox control
Panel panel1 = new Panel();
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

// Set the Text property of the TextBox control
textBox1.Text = "My Text";

// Add the TextBox to the Panel's control collection
panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);

// Add the Panel to the Form's control collection
this.Controls.Add(panel1);

//... subsequent controls
```

Optimizing this code snippet using the top-down and parenting techniques results in the following snippet:

**After optimization:**

```
// Create a new panel and textbox control
Panel panel1 = new Panel();
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

// set parents from top to down
this.panel1.Parent = this;
this.textBox1.Parent = this.panel1;

// Set properties of child control (cause repainting only once)
textBox1.Text = "My Text";

//... subsequent controls
```

> This can make a big difference with a deeply nested control hierarchy.
>   Optimizing the code in the `InitializeComponent` method by creating
>   the controls top-down and re-parenting them resulted in a performance
>   improvement of about 50% over the default Forms Designer generated
>   code!

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: move `this.Controls.Add(this.pnlHeader);` to the top of `InitializeComponent` (before adding any child controls to `pnlHeader`? That makes sense and I'll give it a try now...

Comment: yes, and all other parent controls should be add to their grand parent controls before filling by their child controls.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the answer from `S.Serp` here are some observations to be aware of:

- Replacing `Location` and `Size` with `Bounds` resulted in an average boost of ~15% for form loading.
- Replacing `Controls.Add` with `Parent` resulted in a further boost of ~5-10% (for an impressive total of ~20-25%).
- As `Sefe` points out, manually editing the Designer.cs file is usually only appropriate where you are not making changes in the Designer very often. Any changes made in the Designer will overwrite your manual code. Be warned! This is not a disaster, you simply lose the boost. Either live with the slower form loading or redo the manual changes.
- Be careful to put the `Bounds` call ***after*** setting `Multiline = true;` on `TextBox` controls (if enabled). If you set it before, your control will (unhelpfully) be resized to a single line.
- Be careful with ensuring each child control has the parent set correctly! Open all forms in the Visual Studio Designer after manually editing `InitializeComponent` to see that everything is kosher...but don't edit anything otherwise your changes will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The lines...

```
this.Controls.Add(this.pnlHeader);
```

...and...

```
this.pnHeader.Parent = this;
```

...are equivalent. The control trees they produce are identical. And you should not change the auto-generated code. Your changes will be overwritten the next time the designer writes its updates.

You usually don't have to worry about the designer-generated code. You can concentrate on your part and assume the designer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Sefe. I'm not suggesting the the Designer code is incorrect, only that it can be manually optimised. The linked MSDN blogpost suggested two changes, one of which definitely improves the performance of creating and displaying the form.

Comment: @AlainD: If you want to optimize your code manually, you can not use the designer. In practice I never had an occasion where I needed to manually optimize form creation. It will be invisible to the user.

Comment: This is a rare occasion, admittedly. I'm deploying the .NET code to a device with limited computational resources. Some of the forms are large and take over 1.5s to be fully rendered. The 1st bit of advice shaved a large chunk off that display time already.

Comment: Oh, and just to be clear, I'm manually editing the code in the `Designer.cs` file and not using the Visual Studio Designer (where you lay out the controls).

Comment: @AlainD: You should not edit the designer code. Someone just has to accidentally save from the designer and your changes are gone. Copy/paste the designer code to a different code file and then modify it.

Comment: @Sefe consider we have developed an application (it is finished) and we want to optimize it as well as we can do for some old machine. consider we don't plan to change the design after publishing our program or repeat our manual optimizations again for next release of our app...

Comment: @Sefe: This is a relatively stable application being optimised for some old machines. You are right that the VS Designer will (stupidly) erase my manual code if any changes are made in the Designer, but it is not a terrible burden to redo the changes if something really does need to be added.